# Chart.js: Display Custom Tooltips, always visible on stacked bar-chart

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

In my MVC project, I am using chart.js (v2.8.0) to build a stacked bar-chart, with 3 data-sets.

I need to display custom tooltips, that are always visible, inside the bars, for each dataset. (See the image below.) I am having difficulty understanding how to implement custom-tooltips that are always visible.

[image: Desired End Result]

This is what my current js code for the chart is:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: labelArray,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Green %',
            data: greenData,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,166,149)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(0,166,149)',
            borderWidth: 1,
        },
        {
            label: 'Orange %',
            data: orangeData,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(229,117,31)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(229,117,31)',
            borderWidth: 1,
        },
        {
            label: 'Grey %',
            data: greyData,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(179,179,179)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(179,179,179)',
            borderWidth: 1,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Please, if someone can help me to get some custom tooltips always visible, in the right place in relation to the bars, then I can get it styled up appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the percentage values in the bars, those are called labels, not tooltips (which are what appear when you mouse over an element).

Label functionality is not natively available in Chart.js but can be added via the [datalabels plugin](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/). You'll need to include the plugin via a `script` tag. (*After* the script tag where you load Chart.js!)

The [bar chart sample](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/samples/charts/bar.html) is already quite close to your desired result, but I've merged it with your code in the snippet below to help you along.

You can reference the plugin [formatting documentation](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/formatting.html) to tailor the final result.

```js
var labelArray = ["James", "Mark", "Simon"],
  greenData = [55, 82, 32],
  orangeData = [27, 10, 53],
  greyData = [18, 8, 15];

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labelArray,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Green %',
        data: greenData,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,166,149)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(0,166,149)',
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: 'Orange %',
        data: orangeData,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(229,117,31)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(229,117,31)',
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
      {
        label: 'Grey %',
        data: greyData,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(179,179,179)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(179,179,179)',
        borderWidth: 1,
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: 'white',
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        },
        formatter: function(value, context) {
          return Math.round(value) + '%';
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was after and is working. Now to fine-tune the styling!